# SQLAlchemy: operator LIKE and custom types

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy ORM. I have following custom column type and table-mapped class:

```
class JSONEncodedDict(TypeDecorator):
    impl = VARCHAR

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)

        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value)
        return value

Base = declarative_base()
class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = Column(INT, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(JSONEncodedDict)
    created = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    updated = Column(TIMESTAMP)
```

I want to query objcts using operator 'like':

```
tasks = session.query(Task).filter(Task.description.like("%some pattern%")).all()
```

But as far as I can see, method `process_bind_param` also converts parameter of `like` operator. so in sql trace I see

`...WHERE description LIKE '"%some pattern%"'`

instead of

`...WHERE description LIKE '%some pattern%'`

so no rows are matched.

How can I execute a query with `LIKE` operator the way I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to get around automatic type processing (or force your own with `type_` argument) using [`literal()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal):

```
Task.description.like(literal("%some pattern%"))
```

Comment: Is there a way to access if a `like` clause is being used in the custom type?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to **coerce** the column to a textual form using `cast()` or `type_coerce()` before attempting to use operator like `like`, `contains` or something else:

```py
from sqlalchemy import type_coerce, String

stmt = select([my_table]).where(
    type_coerce(my_table.c.json_data, String).like('%foo%'))
```

or you can do this in your custom type class defination:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import operators
from sqlalchemy import String

class JSONEncodedDict(TypeDecorator):

    impl = VARCHAR

    def coerce_compared_value(self, op, value):
        if op in (operators.like_op, operators.notlike_op):
            return String()
        else:
            return self

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)

        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value)
        return value
```

ref: [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#dealing-with-comparison-operations)